# What effects drawing charts/diagrams from $_SESSION data under php5, which worked under php4?

Tags: php, session, charts, setting

I have a script generating 3 diagrams from $_SESSION variables which work fine under php4 with register_globals = off, but when I parse the same script as php5 I get no diagram.

The diagrams a drawn from GD libary and it works, if I set the data into an Array (manually filled) within the script file. But I need a way to get it work on php5, without much changes.

Are there any SESSION settings or php-settings which might interfere with my script. I already checked a lot of the php-settings (changing php.ini over and over again), but found nothing what brings me the diagrams back.

Hopefully someone of you could kick me into the right direction. Any Ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you getting any error messages? if so, what do they say?

Comment: Chances are, your script is generating errors. Remove your `Content-type` header and check the output.

Comment: When I remove the Content-Type header it brings me an error message for a function which only has a foreach loop to get the $_SESSION array data. 
Hm, but I guess it would be better to open a new question and show some code.
Thanks for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first look at the array created with version 4 and version 5 and compare both. And you sould make a logical data structure, so you can access it without compatiblity problems

Comment: If they are the same, i think your gd lib has some problem but im not sure